# remove dynamically created list in handlebars js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have created dynamically list using handlebars js and its template. i am confused               that how to remove/delete list using any function or code. i am new in handlebars . i am posting some code below please help me . This is my code ..(i want to add button or any thing for perform delete contact on name )

```
<script id="template" type="text/html">
  <ul class="contact">
  {{#container}}
  {{#nid}}
  <li><a href="contact-detail.html?nid={{nid}}">{{name}}</a>
    </li>{{/nid}} 
   {{^nid}}<li><a href="contact-detail.html">No Contacts</a></li>{{/nid}}
   {{/container}}
   </ul>
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add this to your template:

```
<a href="javascript:deleteContact({{nid}})">delete</a>
```

then handle the data deletion in that function and reapply the handlebars template.

Comment: thanks **thomas** , please can you put some few code as example for how to handle data deletion and how to reapply handlebars template  ..i'm totally confused..